# In Rails 3, can we restrict which domains receive emails from our staging server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

We want to test email functionality on our staging server, but we don't want to accidentally email customers.

So, I'd like emails sent to "anything@corporation.com" to work, but emails sent to "anything@customer.com" to be suppressed.

I could just go into all of my controllers and put in code that only fires the "deliver" method if the email contains our domain or the environment is prod.  But, that seems kinda kludgey.  I'd like to do it app wide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applications that use the Mail gem (including rails >= 3.0 projects) can use the safety_mailer gem.  Specify a domain (or set of domains, or magic word in email address) email is allowed to go to, and email to all other domains is silently dropped.

https://github.com/cluesque/safety_mailer

Add the gem to your Gemfile, specifying groups (probably not production) to include it in.

```
gem "safety_mailer", :group => :development
```

Don't forget to bundle install to install

In your environment file config/environments/development.rb configure it, and some regular expressions.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :safety_mailer
SafetyMailer::Config.allowed_matchers = [ /mydomain.com/, /mytestacct@gmail.com/, /super_secret_test/ ]
```

... and now, email to anyone@mydomain.com, mytestacct@gmail.com, bob+super_secret_test@yahoo.com all get sent
and email to other recipients (like the real users in the production database you copied to a test server) is suppressed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with an interceptor:

Create an initializer   `/config/initializers/mailer_config.rb` :

```
require 'staging_mail_interceptor'
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(StagingMailInterceptor) if [test here if on staging server]
```

The file `/lib/staging_mail_interceptor.rb` contains the interceptor, where you can modify the message before it is sent. In my case I tag the subject and redirect all mails to my personal email. You can put here the code to filter the domains:

```
class StagingMailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.subject = "TEST #{message.to} - #{message.subject}"
    message.to = 'test@corporation.com'
  end
end
```

Comment: This is pretty much what we want to do.  Is there a way to stop delivering the email from inside the interceptor?  We'd like to check the domain in the "To:" and then just kill it if it's for a non-local domain.

Comment: `message.to = nil` should stop the delivery :-)

Comment: making the email nil throws a "ArgumentError (At least one recipient (To, Cc or Bcc) is required to send a message)" exception.

Comment: Maybe set `ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = false` and send to a fake email address.

Comment: Looks like you can just set `message.perform_deliveries = false`, see https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/114

Answer (score 1):

[Modify the `delivery_method` option](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) for your staging environment - this is a lot less messy than putting in code in your controllers, and then having to rip it back out, because you simply modify a setting, and change it back.

> `delivery_method` - Defines a delivery method. Possible values are `:smtp`
>   (default), `:sendmail`, `:test`, and `:file`.

In this case you probably want to use `:test`, or `:file`. `:file` will dump the contents of the email to a file so you can be sure that the email is being rendered the way you expect it to be, with the proper names inserted, etc., without actually sending an email out on the interwebs.

Typically, you don't need to make sure that ActionMailer will actually send email - it does, and it's a well tested module all its own.

An alternative solution, if you really need a full-stack test, is to modify the recipient list for staging only. If you're sending the email to a distribution list, then point it to a different distribution list for staging. If you're sending to a list of emails from the database, then temporarily remove (or mark as inactive) the email addresses you don't want to send to.

Comment: [MailCatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher) would be another option, works great for development.